# ViewModel onChanged gets infinite loop

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, android-livedata

i try to practice with mvvm + databinding + livedata
but get into infinite loop.
Please tell me how to fix it, thanks!

here is my code:

### layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.guanhong.mvvmpractice.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".view.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onViewClick"
            android:text="@{@string/player_name(viewModel.dataItem.firstName, viewModel.dataItem.lastName)}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/heightFeet"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onViewClick"
            android:text="@{@string/high_feet(viewModel.dataItem.heightFeet.toString())}"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        viewModel.dataItem.observe(this,
            Observer<DataItem> { dataItem ->

                Log.d("Huang", " MainActivity Observer " + dataItem.firstName)

                viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
            })

        viewModel.init()
    }
}
```

### Repository

```
class MainRepository {

    fun getAllPlayer(callback: GetAllPlayerCallback) {

        val retrofit = Retrofit
            .Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://free-nba.p.rapidapi.com/")
            .build()

        val allPlayerData = retrofit.create(AllPlayerApi::class.java)

        val call = allPlayerData.getAllPlayer(2)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<AllPlayerData> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<AllPlayerData>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Log.d("Huang", " MainRepository get player fail ")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<AllPlayerData>?, response: Response<AllPlayerData>) {

                Log.d("Huang", " MainRepository onResponse ")

                callback.onSuccess(response.body()!!.data!!)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = MainRepository()

    var dataItem = MutableLiveData<DataItem>()

    fun init() {
        getAllPlayer()
    }

    private fun getAllPlayer() {

        repository.getAllPlayer(object : GetAllPlayerCallback {
            override fun onSuccess(dataItemList: List<DataItem>) {

                Log.d("Huang", " MainViewModel getAllPlayer onSuccess ")

                dataItem.value = (dataItemList[0])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Logcat

[logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHihR.png)

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm also facing this problem in while using data binding.

Answer (score 1):

you are updating the observer data inside its callback, so as soon as you call
viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
it gives you a callback and gets stuck in an infinite loop

```html
viewModel.dataItem.observe(this,
            Observer<DataItem> { dataItem ->

                Log.d("Huang", " MainActivity Observer " + dataItem.firstName)

                viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
            })viewModel.dataItem.observe(this,
            Observer<DataItem> { dataItem ->

                Log.d("Huang", " MainActivity Observer " + dataItem.firstName)

                viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
            })
```

Comment: you are rigtht!! But if i use databinding i should update my viewmodel, how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

Because inside your observer function, which observe live data from ViewModel, you are instantly set up new value that update all observer. This is infinity loop. You should not update live data variable from view. The view (fragment, activity) should only observe data.

```
viewModel.dataItem.observe(this,
            Observer<DataItem> { dataItem ->

                Log.d("Huang", " MainActivity Observer " + dataItem.firstName)

                // Problem is below
                // viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
            })
```

Comment: You are rigtht!! But if i use databinding i should update my viewmodel, how can i do it.

Comment: Depends on what type of user interaction is going to update your viewmodel. For example, for a MaterialButton you could have something like mBinding.myButton.onClickListener = someOnClickListenerDefinition, and the someOnClickListenerDefinition will invoke viewModel.doSomethingThatUpdatesViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the problem you faced while using **ViewModel** along with the **Databinding** library. I fixed this by the following approach.

```
  viewModel.dataItem.observe(this,
        Observer<DataItem> { dataItem ->
            //This condition will actually prevent the infinite loop
            if(!(viewModel.dataItem.value?.equals(dataItem))) 
            viewModel.dataItem.value = dataItem
        })
```

Actually you need to set the value when a new value is emitted ignoring the previous value if it remains the same.